# How to set value in textbox getting from LocalStorage in Html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, local-storage

In my html5 page, I am saving user input values to localstorage from textbox using following code :

```
localStorage.setItem("Username",uname);
localStorage.setItem("Password",password);
```

This is working fine and I am able to save data to local storage.Now I want to get data from localstorage and then display in textbox. I know how to get data, I've to use

`localStorage.getItem("Username");`

But I want to display this username to textbox on pageLoad. Can anybody help me how to do this..??

Comment: For security reasons, I'd be very careful about storing a user's password unencrypted in Local Storage. Username is probably fine, but password seems extremely risky.

It'd be especially bad if the site is being served over HTTP rather than HTTPS because the password could be stolen by a MITM injecting extra JS into the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This :-

```
$('#Usertextboxid').val(localStorage.getItem("Username"));
$('#Passtextboxid').val(localStorage.getItem("Password"));
```

Instead of `Usertextboxid`,`Passtextboxid` selector id's give the id's you are using in you page.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript example for username input.

**Onclick event is handled.**

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", save, false);
document.getElementById("restore").addEventListener("click", restore, false);

function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("username", document.getElementById('username').value);
}

function restore() {
  document.getElementById('username').value = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```

Where ids should be set to actual values:

```
<input id="username" type="text"></input>
<input id="save" type="button" value="save"></input>
<input id="restore" type="button" value="restore"></input>
```

**Onload event is handled**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startup() {
    //
    // Initialize local storage
    //
    localStorage.setItem("username", "Hello, world!");

    //
    // Get preinitialized value from local storage
    //
    document.getElementById('username').value = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startup();">
<input id="username" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okk...what u have done is on button click event. How to do this for onpageLoad. I am doing this on page load but it is displaying undefined or say null.

Comment: It is handled almost the same way using onload event.

Comment: no need to set item on page load. because I already set this by entering in textbox. I just want to get item that is stored in local db and then display in textbox. But when I retrieve item then it is showing null.